# Hide a video player if there is no data in database

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

How do I hide a video player if there is no data to be displayed?
[image]

Do I need to use javascript for it?

Here is the code for displaying the video player:

```
        <div id="video-player"> 
        <video width="100%"controls> 
            <source src="{{ asset('workmedia/' . $artpiece->art_vid) }}" type="video/mp4"> 
              Your browser does not support the video tag. 
        </video> 
      </div>
```

Comment: Just test if `art_vid` is an empty string or null and don't render the HTML?

Comment: IMHO it should be solved server-sided. There is no reason to generate and display a video element in the first place if no video is available. Hiding an element client-sided costs you poor accessibility and lower SEO ratings.

Comment: $("#video-player").hide();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`@isset`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#if-statements) blade directive to determine if your `$artpiece->art_vid` has a value and if it does, display the video otherwise don't:

```
@isset($artpiece->art_vid)
<div id="video-player"> 
        <video width="100%"controls> 
            <source src="{{ asset('workmedia/' . $artpiece->art_vid) }}" type="video/mp4"> 
              Your browser does not support the video tag. 
        </video> 
      </div>
@endisset
```